# How do I sniff this RF Transmitter Gate Opener Circuit?

Tags: rf, transmitter

What piece of hardware am I looking for to observe the transmitted radio signal? Would an oscilloscope come in handy here? is this a 2-channel RF remote, a 3channel RF remote, or something else?

My goal is to build my own circuit that emulates this circuit. Would I require a bus pirate for this? I realize it might be much easier just to buy a new remote but I'm using it as a learning experience rather than a cost saving endeavor.

googling the IC, a message board mentions its probably a custom IC. The IC has the following printed on it: 
0412
SEMEFAB
051-8728
0821-D (LF)  D[big letters, on right]
[image]

Comment: The transmission frequency is the most probably determined by L1-C6 oscillator. I guess it has 1 RF channel and it sends 1 of 10 selectable different signals (presets) which are modulated on the RF frequency.

Comment: If you can get access to the modulated digital signal before it hits the RF stage this might be easiest.  However this might be harder if there is one monolithic IC that does all of the processing.  Depending on the frequency of the device your oscilloscope might help if you make a loop and clip the ground wire to the probe, but it's likely to be in the ISM band (4xx/8xx/9xxMhz) which isn't going to appear on your scope.

Comment: You might check the signal at the base of Q1.

Comment: With regards to equipment the traditional method would be a spectrum analyser. Nowadays you might get away with a HackRF and GNU Radio.

Comment: This looks like a 300-310 MH single channel garage door opener such as multicode 308911

Comment: ray it looks like thats what it is. I ended up scanning it with software radio. The thing is it jumps around within that range and I haven't quite figured out how to decode it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd definitely recommend getting a BusPirate, you can probably find the frequency in the developer docs and then do something like this:

http://ms3c.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/basic-rf-sniffing-with-the-bus-pirate/

Failing that you can probe all the pins with the BusPirate logic analyser mode and just observe the transmit waveform.